# How to run the cd command in the terminal through Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run `cd` command in the terminal through my Python script. I just discovered a module called subprocess, do you have any idea why the Popen() method doesn't change the directory in the terminal, it seems like it changes the state only.

```py
    if p:
        return subprocess.Popen(['cd'], cwd = target_dir, shell = True)
    return 'directory does not exist'
```

Terminal:

```sh
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f805ef045e0>
```

When I changed the command, it seems working:

```py
    if p:
        return subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], cwd = target_dir, shell = True)
    return 'directory does not exist'
```

Terminal:

```sh
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ff1ef1ec5e0>
.  ..  projects  books  resources  docs
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Open a terminal and compare the effects of `sh -c ls` and `sh -c cd`.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess` module creates new sub process and changes directory in for that process. it will not change directory of the parent process.

To change current process directory use `os.chdir(target_dir)`

More:

```py
import os
os.chdir(<target_dir>) # to change directory
os.listdir('.') # to list current directory
os.listdir(<target_idr>) # to list target_dir
```